# How can I see the logs for today

Tags: grep

I need to be able to see the logs for current day (access.log 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021:01:45:29 +0300] )
`grep $(date +%d/%b/%y)` - doesn't work (git bash windows)

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** What happened when you tried it?  Did you get an error message? If you did get an error, paste the entire message instead of paraphrasing. Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: I get the wrong result.
I know for a fact that there are 13 lines
But when I run grep $(date +%d/%b/%y) access.log -c
I get 0

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your `date` command, I get this:

```
$ date +%d/%b/%y
04/Mar/21
```

which means that you are calling

```
$ grep 04/Mar/21
```

but you are trying to find lines with

```
05/Mar/2021:01:45:29 +0300
```

What does  `date +%d/%b/%y` show for you?  Are you a day off from the logs you're searching?

Comment: The log line looks like this

access.log:127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2021:08:30:45 +0300] "GET /BingBar/signed/BBSvcConfig.cab HTTP/1.1" 404 196

when I execute  date +%d/%b/%y I get 05/мар/21

Comment: I think I realized my mistake :) date +%d/%b/%Y 
Now I get 05/мар/2021
I still need to figure out how to get the month in the file instead of the current locale
And then we have to merge all this with grep

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept this answer so that others get pointed to it.  The key here is that your assumption of what the date command was returning was not correct, and it's a good lesson.  Every programmer has gone through this before. :-)